# Firebase Console gets stuck while verifying the installation on an iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase

I'm trying to connect IOS app to firebase, everything was going well until I've reached the last step of the connecting process "verifying the installation" and this text pops up "Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.", I'm new to firebase and I have nothing to do with this issue. 
[image]

Comment: uninstall your app and run again and see if it can communicate with firebase

Comment: I've reached out to Firebase support and they've e-mailed me with some options to overcome this obstacle, one of them was to 'Skip this step' and it's doing well right now.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone will also face this issue, here is my solution.

In my case, I've missed the `Firebase/Analytics` installation.

After the `Firebase/Analytics` installation, the verification passed successfully.

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me. The app functioned properly without it, however it just needed FirebaseAnalytics added for it to get rid of that warning in the firebase console.

Answer (score 2):

As the texts says, to complete the step you need to delete the App from your device and Install and Run it again from Xcode. Be sure to follow carefully the previous steps, and to execute the code of the **step 4** in your app initialization (for example in one of the App Delegate methods), where you call the method `FirebaseApp.configure()` (or `[FIRApp configure];` for Obj-C) to start the communication with Firebase.

After starting that communication method you have to wait a few moments and a new message in a green box will appear to confirm that everything went well.

[image: Sorry for the lack of translation of the image]

Also you can simply **skip this step** and if you followed all the other steps correctly, your app will be connected to the Firebase anyways.